# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) using xcode 6 beta6 and deployment target 7.0

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) using xcode 6 beta6 and deployment target 7.0

I tried using pod file and error occurred

Comment: You should give some code for us to check... your question is too broad. The only hint I can give you is to be sure you are opening the workspace and not the project in Xcode.

Comment: yes i am using work space
i have used pod file in which i have used pkreveal library 
but before integrating pod file it was kept in my project which was accessed from bridging header file

Comment: Although it seems you have already your answer for the people that this did not work. I had the same issue and the problem for me was in the Build Settings->Other Linker FLags-> for some reason apart from the inherited flag there were created some other duplicates. Leaving only the inherited flag worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

Go to your project profile

-> build settings

-> Open "Search path"

-> Open "Framework search path"

-> now,double click on path located

-> there are two paths like

(1) $(inherited)

(2) "$(SRCROOT)/../../../Data/myCodes/data/Nav"

-> remove all data of first and second path..Thats it.

Comment: there is nothing in framework search path it is empty only then how should i do it please help me.. thanx in advance

Comment: @jalakpatel please add  $(SRCROOT)/your framework path

Comment: In framework search path nothing is written it is empty so should i write anything in that??
and i am using 3rd party library code used by bridging header so which framework should i add??

Comment: @jalakpatel yes you should add all 3rd party framework path in frame work search path.